# How can I easily find world quests?

Tags: genshin-impact

I have completed every single quest in my quest log but as I work through the Sumeru reputation track, I can see many uncompleted quests.

Is there a good technique for me to be able to find these quests? Or do I need to look each one up on the wiki individually?

Comment: some of them may be tied to an output of a daily commission, like that gourmet supremos that I see in the reputation track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it will mostly be manually going to hunt them down using a wiki as a guide.

This wiki page has a good list of lots of the quests to work from.

https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/World_Quest